# What is a simplest way to create timer and stopwatch in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create a timer or stopwatch for my video player project to count views, for that I want a simple stopwatch to enter my logic for the view counter.

I tried creating the stopwatch and timer using setInterval but that didn't work as I was expecting.

Comment: Please check how to ask a good question in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a customHook for timer

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useTimer = (delay) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    const [stop, isSetStop] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (stop) return
        console.log("TIMER RUNNING=>>>>>>>>>>>");
        setTimeout(() => {
            setState((prev => prev + 1))
        }, delay)
    }, [state])



    return [state, () => isSetStop(true)]
}

export default useTimer
```

use it like this

```
const [time, stopTime] = useTimer(1000)
```

you can reverse it and it will be stopwatch and you can call stopTime method to stop it or you can put condition in useEffect of hook

```
useEffect(() => {
            if (stop || state >= 60 ) return
            console.log("TIMER RUNNING=>>>>>>>>>>>");
            setTimeout(() => {
                setState((prev => prev + 1))
            }, delay)
        }, [state])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It was the really simplest way to understand and apply in my view counter logic.

Comment: this hook has a problem, if you minimise the app and come back after like half or one minute later, it will start from where you left the timer. To sove this, save the time stamp when you atarted the timer and keep rectifying it on basis of that initial timestamp

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but my issue was solved for view counter logic by the above method. your comment will be useful for future developers who want to create a proper stopwatch.